# How to find combinations of a list in a Dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, permutation

I am trying to find any permutation of a list inside another Dictionary with tuples.

For example, what would be the best way to find any combination of `[1,2,3]` inside of a Dictionary which is formatted like this: `{(1,3,2):'text',(3,1,2):'text'}`.

The only matches that would qualify for `[1,2,3]` would be `(1,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,1,3),(2,3,1),(3,2,1),(3,1,2)`.

Matches that wouldn't qualify include Lists that don't contain all of the items (For example: `(1,2)` or `(2)`), and matches that contain extra items (for example:`(1,2,3,4)` or `(2,3,7,1)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.permutations()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) to generate all permutations of a list:

```
from itertools import permutations

if any(tuple(perm) in yourdictionary for perm in permutations(yourlist)):
    # match found
```

but you really want to rethink your data structure. If you made your keys `frozenset()` objects instead, you simply would test for:

```
if frozenset(yourlist) in yourdictionary:
    # match found
```

which would be a *lot* faster.

Demos:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> yourdictionary = {(1,3,2):'text',(3,1,2):'text'}
>>> yourlist = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print any(tuple(perm) in yourdictionary for perm in permutations(yourlist))
True
>>> yourdictionary = {frozenset([1, 2, 3]): 'text', frozenset([4, 5, 6]): 'othertext'}
>>> frozenset(yourlist) in yourdictionary
True
>>> frozenset([2, 3]) in yourdictionary
False
```

Comment: Yeah, now that you point it out. it seems rediculous that I didn't just change the format to an organized one.  Thanks a lot.